# 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\x90' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, python-2.7, unicode, encoding, scikits

I'm using Python 2.7 to read the Book-Crossings dataset using Surprise Library.
I had an Encoding problem.
Here is my code:

```
 #load book_ratings dataset which contains (user-id, ISBN and book rating [0..10])
df = pd.read_csv("Desktop\ML project\BX-CSV-Dump\BX-Book-Ratings.csv", sep=';',encoding = "CP1252")
# Create the reader in the proper format
reader = Reader(line_format='user item rating', sep=';', rating_scale=(0,10))
ratings = Dataset.load_from_df(df, reader)

# Test that surprise is working by running SVD on the dataset
ratings.split(5)
algo = SVD()
evaluate(algo, ratings, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'])
```

The exception I get:

```
UnicodeEncodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-23-03cf8b43a4db> in <module>()
      9 ratings.split(5)
     10 algo = SVD()
---> 11 evaluate(algo, ratings, measures=['RMSE', 'MAE'])

C:\Users\Jihed Mestiri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scikit_surprise-latest-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\surprise\evaluate.pyc
in evaluate(algo, data, measures, with_dump, dump_dir, verbose)
     66         # train and test algorithm. Keep all rating predictions in a list
     67         algo.train(trainset)
---> 68         predictions = algo.test(testset, verbose=(verbose == 2))
     69 
     70         # compute needed performance statistics

C:\Users\Jihed Mestiri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scikit_surprise-latest-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.pyc
in test(self, testset, verbose)
    150                                     r_ui_trans - self.trainset.offset,
    151                                     verbose=verbose)
--> 152                        for (uid, iid, r_ui_trans) in testset]
    153         return predictions
    154 

C:\Users\Jihed Mestiri\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\scikit_surprise-latest-py2.7-win-amd64.egg\surprise\prediction_algorithms\algo_base.pyc
in predict(self, uid, iid, r_ui, clip, verbose)
     93             iiid = self.trainset.to_inner_iid(iid)
     94         except ValueError:
---> 95             iiid = 'UKN__' + str(iid)
     96 
     97         details = {}

UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe8' in position 4: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I tried with other encoding codes but it didn't work too. It delivers similar error.

Comment: Can you provide the whole traceback?

Comment: You have hit an implicit encoding issue. Without the traceback we can't tell where this happens however. Python 2 will implicitly encode Unicode strings when combined with byte strings, or when printing.

Comment: The character is [codepoint U+0090](https://codepoints.net/U+0090), a control character. This could well indicate that you picked the wrong codec for your input data. Are you *sure* you have codepage 1252 data?

Comment: @stamaimer I added the traceback. Sorry, didn't know that it's essential.

Comment: @MartijnPieters it's English, so 1252 should work? I tried with codec: ascii & cp037. Also pandas didn't deliver any error when reading the file.

Comment: No, CP1252 is an encoding that will decode *any binary file*, but that doesn't mean the result will be readable. You could also have Latin-1 data, and again that codec will decode anything. Most 8-bit codecs will do that, you simply need to figure out what the correct codec really is.

Comment: That said, the file apparently contains non-ascii characters, and it seems that the bit of Anaconda code there can't deal with non-ascii `iid` values even if they are decoded correctly?

Comment: I'm not familiar with scikit toolkits to be able to give any kind of useful advice here, sorry. The error is caused by the library trying to concatenate a bytestring with a Unicode string; this triggers an implicit encode to ASCII, which fails as you don't have ASCII-clean data.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I would ask, have u any hints to ' to figure out what the correct codec really is'?